# Why is my database connection failing?

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
import pyodbc

exFile = r'C:\Python34\pqr.xlsx'
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ='+exFile,autocommit=True)

curs1 = conn1.cursor()
excel_results = curs1.execute('select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$]').fetchall()
print (excel_results)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/new.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ='+exFile,autocommit=True)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] External table is not in the expected format. (-5015) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Why does this connection gives this error?

Comment: Because the driver is for `*.xls` and your file is `.xlsx` may be?

Comment: no I dont think this is the correct ans. because when I did this last time it got executed and now it is showing above error.

Comment: import pyodbc

exFile = r'C:\Python34\pqr.xlsx'
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ='+exFile,autocommit=True)

curs1 = conn1.cursor()
excel_results = curs1.execute('select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$] where context_id = 769;').fetchall()
p = (excel_results)
f1 = open("xyz.suite", "w")
for x in p:
    f1.write(x[0])
    f1.write("\n")
f1.close()

Answer (score 0):

carefully check this line in program : insert ";" after sheet.

excel_results = curs1.execute('select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$];').fetchall()